# React router <Redirect> is not redirecting on state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, local-storage, react-router-dom, react-state

The app should redirect to `/dashboard` when `user` is not `null`. User is `null` in the first render but `useEffect()` should pick up and store user data from local storage. Then, the ternary operator should trigger `<Redirect to='/dashboard' />` and redirects to dashboard page. But, it's not doing that. It just keeps showing the login page at `/login` whenever I refresh even if there is data in localStorage.

What am I doing wrong or how can I solve this?

```
const App = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')

        if (loggedUserJSON) {
            const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
            setUser(user)
            noteService.setToken(user.token)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/'>
                    {user
                        ? <Redirect to='/dashboard' />
                        : <Redirect to='/login' />
                    }
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/login'>
                    <LogIn />
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard'>
                    <Dashboard />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that on the initial render the `user` state is `null` and the redirect to "/login" occurs. When you reload the page, if the path is still "/login" it doesn't ***exactly*** match "/" and no redirect occurs, regardless of `user` state.

## Solution

Initialize state from localStorage instead of waiting a render cycle. This at least allows you to check the `user` state on the first render instead of on the second (or later) rerender. Reorder the routes in the `Switch` component to specify them from *more* specific to *less* specific. The redirect should come last so other paths have a chance to be matched and rendered first.

```
const initializeState = () => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'));

const App = () => {
  const [user] = useState(initializeState());

  useEffect(() => {
    noteService.setToken(user.token);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login'>
          <LogIn />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/dashboard'>
          <Dashboard />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to={user ? '/dashboard' : '/login'} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

This doesn't quite resolve the page reload issue where a user is already on a sub-route. For this you *should* implement a `ProtectedRoute` component and pass the `user` state as a prop. If there is an `user` object it renders a regular `Route` component and passes the props on through, otherwise it renders a `Redirect` and bounces the user to the login route.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ user, ...props }) => user ? (
  <Route {...props} />
) : (
  <Redirect to="/login" />
);

const initializeState = () => JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser'));

const App = () => {
  const [user] = useState(initializeState());

  useEffect(() => {
    noteService.setToken(user.token);
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login'>
          <LogIn />
        </Route>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/dashboard' user={user} >
          <Dashboard />
        </ProtectedRoute>
        <Redirect to={user ? '/dashboard' : '/login'} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 6, read this: [reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

Specifically the part where it tells you to remove any `<Redirect>` elements that are directly inside a `<Switch>`.

Comment: Hi! Can you please provide the citation of said 'part' directly in your answer? Links usually die and/or changes their content within a timeframe.

Comment: ReactRouter > Read the docs > Upgrading to V6 > Upgrading from v5 > Remove <Redirect>s inside <Switch>

Comment: I meant typing in your answer the relevant part of the documentation (an extract) so it's available right here on SO.